# Strange characters from JSON causing line breaks in my UILabel

Tags: json, swift, text, uilabel

I retrieve and parse JSON for my app after making a networking request. The text I parse often has some random code that reoccurs and causes line breaks in my labels. For example:

```
"...it turns\u{0C}aggressive..."
```

I was wondering what the significance of this is, and how to remove this from all the texts I am receiving so as to avoid arbitrary line breaks in my text. I am coding this in Swift and have read documentation on String class but I do not really know how to identify my problem, which makes it harder to find a solution. Not sure what \u{0C} stands for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a Swift string literal, `\u{n}` is the escape sequence for
the Unicode code point `U+n` (`n` a 1-8 digit hexadecimal number).

So `\u{0C}` is `U+000C` which is is the ["form feed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break) character. This causes the unwanted line break.

You can simply replace it with a regular space character:

```
let text = "...it turns\u{0C}aggressive..."
let modified = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{0C}", with: " ")
print(modified) // ...it turns aggressive...
```

Alternatively, replace all "whitespace" (newline, carriage return, form feed, tabulator) with a regular space character:

```
let modified = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second option? What is \\s and how does targeting that remove all white spaces?

Comment: @EmanH: `\s` is a *regular expression pattern* and matches all whitespace characters.